# Site has no styling after APC is installed

Tags: php, css, centos, cpanel, apc

I recently installed APC on my dedicated server, and now my site's CSS is not being read at all. Or so I think because the site has no styling.

Any ideas how I can fix this? 
The site has the following installed:

APC 3.1.9   -   PHP 5.4.10   -   CENTOS 5.9 x86_6   -   WHM 11.34.1. (Build 7)   -   cPanel of the same version as WHM   -   Perl Version 5.8.8   -   mod_fcgid 2.3.6   -   SocialEngine 4.2.5

Any feedback is very welcome

Comment: I forgot to mention site was running perfectly fine (but slow) when it didn't have APC. Now apc.php shows it is caching.

Comment: It seams to be a problem of you software and its cache. Can you please provide a link to the site? Try to clear the cache or ask the manfucator of socialengine.

Comment: Have you verified that you can't successfully directly access the CSS file?

Comment: I have tried flushing APC's cache and the problem still persists. Cryptic how would I test that? the .css file is not part of the list of cached files in apc.php. Also, SocialEngine has built in support for APC, and it is set to be using APC.

Answer (score 0):

So I enabled suEXEC, graceful restarted the server and that solved the problem. Just writing this in case someone else has the same issue happening to them.